# sort() function does not give the expected result

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python, and I was trying to get the below posted Python code to work but unfortunately, it does not give me the expected or the correct result.

I am trying to sort a simple list contains numbers using the built-in method sort() and after executing the program I get NONE as a result.

Please guide me to solve this problem.

**Python code**

```
a=[7,4,0,-5,30,2,11,84,6]
b=a.sort()
print(b)
```

Answer (score 5):

`list.sort` sorts the list inplace, thus returning `None`

Instead use the `sorted` function which returns the sorted list

```
b = sorted(a)
```

Comment: or for your example code you give, you can just do: `a=[…]` `a.sort()` `print a`

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` is an *inplace* sort. It sorts the list, but doesn't return it (it actually returns `None`).

```
>>> a=[7,4,0,-5,30,2,11,84,6]
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[-5, 0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 11, 30, 84]
```

To get the sorted list separately, use `sorted()`:

```
>>> a=[7,4,0,-5,30,2,11,84,6]
>>> b = sorted(a)
>>> b
[-5, 0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 11, 30, 84]
>>> a
[7, 4, 0, -5, 30, 2, 11, 84, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.sort()` sorts `a` and returns `None`. Try this:

```
a=[7,4,0,-5,30,2,11,84,6]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `.sort()` do not return a list object it returns `None`.

If you look at this example you can see how a is sorted without assigning to b.

```
>>> a=[7,4,0,-5,30,2,11,84,6]
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[-5, 0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 11, 30, 84]
```